# Anaconda prompt giving error while opening

Tags: python, anaconda

I am receiving the below error while starting Anaconda Prompt adding on I am not able to open Anaconda Navigator. Is there any way to resolve this?

> Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module
> Python runtime state: initialized

[image]

Comment: A stack trace may contain valuable hints to the root cause, so it is usually a good idea to add it to the question.

Comment: Okay, I have added full image of error. let me know if this is not what you meant.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.