# Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module in Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, anaconda3

When I launch Anaconda Prompt I get the following error message:

> Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module
> Python runtime state: initialized
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\blue-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site.py", line 73, in 
> import os
> File "C:\Users\blue-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\os.py", line 29, in 
> from _collections_abc import _check_methods
> File "C:\Users\blue-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib_collections_abc.py", line 12, in 
> GenericAlias = type(list[int])
> TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

This question was asked previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64528087/anaconda-prompt-giving-error-while-opening), but it wasn't answered so I'm trying my luck by asking it again.

Sidenote: I don't know if this is relevant information, but I also can't open the Anaconda Navigator or any Anaconda apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you running another python3 set up in your machine ? Because this error occurs when more than one python environment is there. The best solution is to uninstall other python versions set up and do clean installation.  Other solutions will be.
a) Check your .bashrc file (if using Ubuntu) and remove the PATH variables to other python versions and only keep the PATH variable for Anaconda.

b) Run the python scripts specific python binary.

```
/home/username/Programs/anaconda3/bin/python3 file.py
```

I hope, these solutions will work

Comment: This worked, I no longer get the error! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into this error.  I had made a file called `types.py` which must have confused python.  Renaming the file solved the issue for me.

Comment: How weird!! Thank you - this saved me a lot of time haha

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and just went to Windows explorer and delete the python file which I was programming last time. Now, I have no problems :)